# Find the force on a square loop in a magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields

Suppose that the magnetic field in some region has the form:    $$B=kz({\bf \hat{x}})$$

(where k is a constant)

Find the force on a square loop (side a), lying in the yz plane and centred at the origin, if it carries a current I, following counter clockwise when you look down that x-axis

[image]

My attempt at solution:

> [image: Blockquote]

However this is not the correct answer, as everything cancel out, can anyone explain this.

Comment: You seem not to be taking account of $z$ being a variable. For the left and right sides of the coil, this means that $z=-\frac a2$ and $\frac a2$. For the top and bottom sides, $z$ varies linearly.